# iOS AFNetworking Response Serializers: Many serializers for each response, or One Serializer To Rule Them All?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0. I have several different calls to make to the back end, each with different responses (all JSON, though). Is it better to make many different serializers, one for each call, or should I make one serializer, and let it handle all of the requests? Also, is it a good idea to have a special serializer for errors?

Comment: You probably don't need to make any serializers.  The `responseObject` in your completion block should have everything you need.

Comment: This is a valid question. For example, Google places API has several types of response formats depending on nearby/radar/something-else being used. I would like to configure request specific response serializer which could be very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

We can plugin multiple response serializers using [`AFCompoundResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFCompoundResponseSerializer.html)

Example

```
NSArray *serializers = @[[iRemoteWalletResponseSerializer serializer]];
sSharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:serializers];
```